# Windows 11 File Explorer items order

Tags: windows

I am using Windows 11 and I still can't find a way to see files first in the explorer when I am using default sort applied (which is by `Name`).

Although you can see files first when choose the `Date modified` sort, is there a way to have it for the default sort?

Comment: Historically, Windows has always preferred to sort folders & files separately, with folders first. If you ever open a window that hasn't a sort value already set by the user, this is what it will default to. [You're not the only one who finds this infuriating. It's actually in my top 5 reasons for disliking Windows as an OS - though of course entirely 'just my opinion'.] Mac default sorts by name, it doesn't care whether its a file or a folder. Neither OS has a simple switch to flip this behaviour, meaning people who prefer folders first hate how Mac sorts… & vice versa. Lose/lose.

Comment: Yeah I see, it makes sense finally

Comment: You can, as I noted in my answer, set Sort by Name. If you set for All Folders, it is reasonably durable. Not perfect but it works well enough in the absence of a 3rd parry App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative answer : File Explorer has always sorted folders first in
ascending sort of "Name".

File Explorer is not customizable and has no add-ons that can modify the
sort.

You may need to to use a third-party products, which are more customizable
than File Explorer.

See [Alternatives to File Explorer](https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/?license=free&sort=likes)
where you will find 118 alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 Explorer has worked the same way for Sorting for quite a long time.

Open Windows Explorer,

Set a top level folder (the highest level main folder you have) to sort the way you wish. I have found over time (several versions of Windows) that Name Sort order is easy to set as outlined below and normally stays set.

The top menu, near the right, three dots  .....  and the Options sub window opens.

View Tab in this sub windows.  See Folder View.

Click on Apply to Folders.

Now File Explorer will come up in your default sort order.

File Explorer views are not completely permanent (you need a third party App for that), so you may need to set your sort order from time to time.

[image: File Explorer View]

xPlorer2 (Zabkat) has settings to keep order permanently until changed